# Input losing focus after typing a character

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/danielbeckera/soccer-app?file=/src/components/SignupModal.js) is my code.

When I type something on the password/password confirmation/email (inside the Sign up modal) I'm able to just type a character and it loses focus on the specific input.
What should I do?
I tried adding a key to the inputs, unsuccessfully.
I saw that this could happen when rendering a component inside a function, but that is not the case too.

```
export default function SignupModal(props) {
  // Abertura do modal
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  // Seleção do estado/cidade
  const [estados, setEstados] = useState([]);
  const [estadoSelecionado, setEstadoSelecionado] = useState("");
  const [cidadesDoEstado, setCidadesDoEstado] = useState([]);
  const [cidadeSelecionada, setCidadeSelecionada] = useState("");
  // Seleção de senhas do modal
  const [primeiraSenha, setPrimeiraSenha] = useState("");
  const [segundaSenha, setSegundaSenha] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleChangeEstado = (e) => {
    setEstadoSelecionado(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleChangeCidade = (e) => {
    setCidadeSelecionada(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleChangePrimeiraSenha = (e) => {
    setPrimeiraSenha(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleChangeSegundaSenha = (e) => {
    setSegundaSenha(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleChangeEmail = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getCities() {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados/${estadoSelecionado}/distritos`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setCidadesDoEstado(data);
    }
    getCities();
  }, [estadoSelecionado]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getStates() {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados"
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setEstados(data);
    }
    getStates();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Dialog
      sx={{ visibility: props.visibleOn }}
      open={handleClickOpen}
      onClose={handleClose}
    >
      {...}
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `visibility` of the `Dialog` to `visible` while the `Dialog` is still close (the `open` state is `false`, you never use it), which leads to unexpected result. To fix it, you need to remove the `visibility` property and use the `open` prop to toggle the `Dialog` state instead:

```
// <Dialog sx={{ visibility: props.visibleOn }}
<Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
```

The `open` state is updated when the `props.openVisible` from the outside changes:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(props.visibleOn);

useEffect(() => {
  setOpen(props.visibleOn);
}, [props.visibleOn]);
```

Because `open` from `Dialog` accepts a boolean value, you also have to change the `visibleOn` to `true`/`false` instead of `visible`/`hidden`:

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

const handleClickOpen = () => {
  setVisible(true);
};

const handleClose = () => {
  setVisible(false);
};
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]